# Terminology: Restrictions of maps without loss of preimages

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map on some sets, $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.

It holds that $f(U) \subseteq f(X) \cap V$.

Is there a notion or name for the restricted map $f|_U: U \to V$ if it satisfies $f(U) = f(X) \cap V$?

EDITED: In other words, I would like that for any element $v \in V$ which has *some* preimage under $f$ we have already a preimage in $U$.

Informally speaking, if we restrict $f$ to $U$ then we *do not lose* preimages of elements in $V$.

If it helps the terminology, one may assume that $f|_U$ is injective.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence starting by "In other words". Take $X = \{0,1\}$, $U = \{0\}$, $Y = V = \{0\}$ and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Then $f(U) = f(X) = V = f(X) \cap V$. However, $f(1) \in V$ but $1 \notin U$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a careless formulation. Thank you for pointing out that mistake.